# PriorityQueue (Java), overwrite comparator with Long

Tags: java

```
PriorityQueue<Point> pq = new PriorityQueue(10, new Comparator<Point>(){
        public long compare(Point a, Point b) {
            long disA = (a.x - origin.x) * (a.x - origin.x) + (a.y - origin.y) * (a.y - origin.y);
            long disB = (b.x - origin.x) * (b.x - origin.x) + (b.y - origin.y) * (b.y - origin.y);
            if (disA == disB) {
                return (long)(a.x - b.x);
            }
            else {
                return disA - disB;
            }
        }
    });
```

I am wirting PriorityQueue and overwrite the Comparator, but I need to use Long instead of int. Because disA and disB may overflow. But compiler says that there is something wrong in my code. I don't know why. Anyone help me plz.

Comment: *What does the compiler say is wrong* ?

Comment: `public *int* compare`. And don't use subtraction, use `Long.compare(a.x, b.x)`, for example.

Answer (score 8):

The [`Comparator.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) method *has to* return `int`. That's just how the interface defines the method:

```
public int compare(Point a, Point b) {
```

I assume you think you have to return `long` because the subtractions yield expressions of type `long`. For one thing, don't use subtractions, in case they overflow.

Instead, use [`Long.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compare-long-long-), which returns `int`:

```
return Long.compare(b.x, a.x);
return Long.compare(disB, disA);
```

Comment: what a smart solution!